# Firebase firestore timestamp is decoded inaccurately in Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm storing a Timestamp data type in Firestore. I set 4 documents to have the same timestamp down to the seconds, which I did via the firestore dashboard. Yet when I decode it in Swift using the Date and Timestamp value, it always comes out different by the nanoseconds. Therefore I can't query the documents based on timestamp equality.

Is there any fix for this? Or am I using the wrong data type?

Here is the model struct:

```
struct Product: Decodable {
    var end_dateTime: Timestamp?
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case end_dateTime
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.end_dateTime = try container.decodeIfPresent(Timestamp.self, forKey: .end_dateTime)
    }
}
```

parsed like so:

```
for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
    do {
        let product = try document.data(as: Product.self)
        result.append(product)
        print("parsed date: \(product.end_datetime)")
    } catch {
        print("Error parsing product: \(error)")
    }
}
```

and below is the parsed timestamp:

```
parsed date: Optional(<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1701360000 nanoseconds=937000000>)
parsed date: Optional(<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1701360000 nanoseconds=528000000>)
parsed date: Optional(<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1701360000 nanoseconds=609000000>)
parsed date: Optional(<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1701360000 nanoseconds=979000000>)
```

and because of the difference in parsed timestamp, this query will not work

```
firestore
    .collection("products")
    .whereField("end_datetime", isEqualTo: endDate)
    .getDocuments {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: From the parse timestamp output it's clear that the nanoseconds value differs, so an equality check won't work. How do you initialize this field when you're writing these documents? Ideally you'd be using a single `Timestamp` object for all of these, as that guarantees there can only be one value.

Comment: You're printing `product.end_datetime`, but you're not showing where that value comes from, or how you are writing it, so we can't see what you might be doing wrong or where your expectation is not being met.  Please edit the question to show enough detail that anyone can use to duplicate the results you observe.

Comment: hi @FrankvanPuffelen, I set the Timestamp object on all of the documents using the Firestore dashboard UI, and I made sure that they have the exact value down to the seconds, so I didn't set the nanoseconds value and I don't know if it's done by the Firestore side or when decoded in Swift.

Comment: @DougStevenson the `product` is the object being parsed on the do catch block, and the `end_datetime` is the product's property, as shown in the Product struct on the first code block.

Comment: Maybe you should write code to set all the timestamp fields to the exact same timestamp object instance instead of using the console.  The console isn't really meant for regular data entry. It's meant for experimentation and debugging.

Comment: HI @DougStevenson, I tried your suggestion and it worked. Though one caveat is that when parsing, even though Swift parses the firestore timestamp to Date object consistently every time (no nanoseconds difference), the equality query still doesn't work, but if I parse it to the Timestamp object the query works. Maybe it should be mentioned in the Firestore documentation because it uses the Date object. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community for the benefits of others

---

As mentioned by @Doug Stevenson:

> Maybe you should write code to set all the timestamp fields to the exact same timestamp object instance instead of using the console. The console isn't really meant for regular data entry. It's meant for experimentation and debugging.

Reference:

- [Firebase Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp)